# Is it possible to pass arguments in Apollo mocks?

Tags: node.js, graphql, mocking, apollo, apollo-server

In the Apollo [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/testing/mocking/) it shows this example:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
    resolved: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    resolved: () => 'Resolved',
  },
};

const mocks = {
  Int: () => 6,
  Float: () => 22.1,
  String: () => 'Hello',
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  mocks,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`)
});
```

I want to be able to pass in an argument, such as an ID into it, like:

```
const mocks = {
  Job: (id) => {
      return somearray.filter(_id === id)
  },
};
```

Is this possible with Apollo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Apollo server V3 you need to use a different kind of code. It has some breaking changes from V2.

You can do that by following the code below:

```
import { buildClientSchema } from 'graphql';
import { addMocksToSchema } from '@graphql-tools/mock';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';

const schema = buildClientSchema(myGqlSchemaJson);


const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: schema,
});

const schemaWithMocks = addMocksToSchema({
  schema: executableSchema,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      myCustomQuery: (_parent: any, args: any, teste: any) => {
        if (args.url === '/stack-overflow') {
          return {data: 'Cool website', url: args.url}
        }
      },
    },
  },
});


const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: schemaWithMocks,
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it work when the returned object has an interface?

I'm returning `{data: 'something', nested: {__typename: 'MyType, data: 'other'}'}` and the outer data is displayed correctly but the the nested becomes null and gives back an Unexpected error. It works if I put this object in `mocks` instead of `resolvers` but then I'm not able to filter based on the ID.